# Why won't Ubuntu 20.10 Boot on VirtualBox with a Windows 10 Host flashing cursor?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a Windows 10 Host that I have ensured HyperV is turned off along with Device Guard. I have also ensured virtualization is turned on (I have an Asus Z590).

When I boot I get a black screen with a blinking cursor. If I boot then hit e and replace `quiet splash` with `text` I get...

[image]

I also tried adding `nomodeset` still the same issue

When I try with 20.04 I get...

[image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the asus docs where that is diff and the task manager says virtualization is enabled

Comment: These are the steps I followed... https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1043786/

Comment: Thank you downgrading helped to get the right answer but once I found it I could install either

Answer (score 0):

I got it, in the Virtual box settings for the image it defaults to 32bit Linux I needed to make it 64bit.